# how do i know what parameters a python function takes with wingware IDE

Tags: python

in visual  studio all you had to do was type the first parenthesis and it showed you the parameters required.

It's not doing that in python / wingware, what is the best / easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of the WingIDE.
In the free version (WingIDE101) you will not get any hints to your code.
You have to buy at least personal license and you will see something like this: [image: WingIDE Personal]

This works for imported and built in modules as well

Answer (score 0):

Python is a "dynamically-typed" programming language, that meaning that the odds are against the IDE in providing code-intelligence.

That said, Wing-IDE is the very best for Python, and there are a few things you can do: first be sure to have open the "Source Assistant" panel, i.e., press F2 and locate it to your right. Second, be sure to inform the IDE of what Python interpreter are you using, as well as any particular Python path that your project might be using; all of that you can do in Project/Project Properties. Finally, you still might need to give hints sometimes to the IDE about your instances with "assert isinstance(x,SomeType)".

Admittedly, is not as straightforward as using Visual Studio, but the good reasons to use Python and its very capable ecosystem, or the easy integration with C/C++ more than compensate.

Comment: [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) doesn't do a half-bad job with its code completion and generating necessary arguments, actually...

Comment: Nor does Komodo, I've no idea where this "dynamic language IDEs can't provide code intelligence" belief comes from.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor It comes from fact :). What would you like to complete for `foo = eval(urllib2.urlopen("http://example.org/myobject").read())`? How about `2 if foo() else "bar"`?

Comment: What does that have to do with the claim that Python IDEs cannot readily show function signatures?

Comment: @Blender the one I just alluded to -- that you cannot know what attributes an arbitrary object has without executing the code.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor What attributes does the object there have? If it is a function, what signature does it have? Perhaps you would prefer `if foo: def bar(x, y, z): return y;; else: def bar(a, b): return a * b`

Comment: @Julian: That's not fact. You're arguing with corner cases. If you happen to run `import inspect; print(inspect.getargspec(bar))` after this code, you'd be given a nice list of arguments.

Comment: @Blender It's fact of course, we can argue about whether it's a corner case or not if you'd like, but that's not really interesting to argue about, especially since I can give you plenty of common cases if you'd like -- you're probably sitting a few lines away from a function that sometimes returns `None` and sometimes returns some value. The point is it isn't possible to do arbitrary completion on Python code without execution. Of course you can run `inspect`, that was exactly my point, although `inspect` can fail too.

Comment: @Julian: [PyDev](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_complctx.html) somehow manages to provide pretty adequate code completion without executing the code. Python can modify objects dynamically, but that doesn't prevent you from using code completion.

Comment: @Julian: If you can't state your point, you don't really have one. Could you point out who challenged that statement? Makato and MatthewTrevor just suggested IDEs that provide decent Python code intelligence.

Comment: OP said "odds are against..." in relation to **providing function signatures automatically in the IDE**, which is what I objected to, as there are clearly IDEs which provide this. If you take "code completion" *out* of that context, then sure, you can make up as many imaginary examples which violate your definition as you like. Does it answer the original question? No. Is it pedantry without point? Absolutely.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor I can not find the part of my answer where I said that WingIDE can not show function signatures or other kind of information. "Odds against" means that it is harder for the IDE, not impossible. It makes good guesses pretty often, but it is not as infallible, as say, a Java IDE, or archi-famous  Visual Studio with intelli-sense.